# Get datatypes of columns of dataframe with loop

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I want to access the datatypes of the columns of the dataframe with a loop, then query if these datatypes are one of the datatypes entered in a list? How can I do that?

This is how the code looks.

```
for(col in colnames(df)){
    if(st(col) in ("category", "object", "bool")){
    print(col)
    }
   }
```

In the loop, fetch the columns of the dataframe,
Comparing the types of these columns with the data types in the list with the if query. As a result of this comparison, the correct ones are print.

Comment: what function is `st()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates how you can achieve your goal

```
df <- data.frame(v1=integer(10),v2=numeric(10),v3=character(10),
             v4=logical(10)) #a sample data.frame
Types = c('integer','logical') # the types you desired
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  if (class(df[,i]) %in% Types)  print(names(df)[i])
}
```

Comment: when done this way it does not return the type of columns of the dataframe. It returns the character result because the names of the columns are characters.

Comment: But that's what you meant in your question post, since you want to `col` which comes from `for(col  in colnames(df))`...